# Including External Python Source as Readonly Text in Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I need to keep certain Python files outside the notebook because they need to be called from outside shell scripts. But I wanted to show / include the code for these external files as well; I see there is a %loadpy magic that include code with syntax highlighting. However this usage seems to include code as real notebook code, so code is editable. I would like the code to show up as readonly, not be editable so I know code in the external file is always the master. For read only code inclusion, I used

```
print open("source.py").read()
```

in my notebook. The code above is ran from a cell which displays the code right below. I was wondering though if there is a better way to do this? Using IPython.ext perhaps? Because the output from code above has no syntax highlighting.